# Objective-C inheritance problem

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

I'm doing the following:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "CCMenuItem.h"


@interface SmartMenuItem : CCMenuItemSprite {

}

@end
```

Then I want to use my class:

```
SmartMenuItem *playItem = [SmartMenuItem itemFromNormalSprite:play
                                                     selectedSprite:playPressed
                                                             target:self 
                                                           selector:@selector(onPlayPressed)];
SmartMenuItem *optionsItem = [SmartMenuItem itemFromNormalSprite:options
                                                        selectedSprite:optionsPressed
                                                                target:self
                                                              selector:@selector(onOptionsPressed)];

[menu_ addChild:playItem];
[menu_ addChild:optionsItem];
```

And i got errors and warnings. Menu accepts `CCMenuItemSprite` as child. But xcode says: Cannot initialize a parameter of type `CCNode*` with an lvalue of type `SmartMenuItem*`.

And also it gives warnings when i'm creating `playItem` and `optionsItem`: method not found. But it is a static method of CCmenuItemSprite!

What's the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem was in adding files to xcode project. They were shared incorrectly.